# Add file to an existing folder if file doesn't exist in that folder

Tags: google-apps-script

So far I have the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var lema = 'house';
  var trad = 'casa';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B_5BQ4yVTu...');
  var doc1 = DriveApp.createFile(lema + ' [ie] ' + trad, '~');
  var doc2 = DriveApp.createFile(trad + ' [ei] ' + lema, '~');
  folder.addFile(doc1);
  folder.addFile(doc2);
}
```

It creates two files (**`doc1`** and **`doc2`**) and moves them to the specified **`folder`**, even if the two files already exist.

Please help me to improve this code so it adds the two files only if they **don't** exist. Is it possible to check if a file exist using only it's name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create files directly inside the destination folder.

```
function myFunction() {
  var lema = 'house';
  var trad = 'casa';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B_5BQ4yVTu...');
  var fileName1 = lema + ' [ie] ' + trad;
  if (!folder.getFilesByName(fileName1).hasNext()) {
    folder.createFile(fileName1, '~');
  }
  var fileName2 = lema + ' [ei] ' + trad;
  if (!folder.getFilesByName(fileName2).hasNext()) {
    folder.createFile(fileName2, '~');
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Amit.